# Specific codes for a dat file that contains bytes (Python)

Tags: python

I have another doubt related to reading the dat file.

The file format is DAT file (.dat)

The content inside the file is in bytes.

When I tried the run open file code, the program built and ran successfully. However, the python shell has no output (I can't see the contents from the file).

Since the content inside the file is in bytes, should I modify the code ? What is the code to use for bytes?

Thank you.

Comment: Could you post your code so far?

Comment: Hi Tim, with open("File.dat", "rb") as f:
    data = f.read() This is the code that I've used.

Comment: Hi, if this is all your code then you are missing a print statement to get the data displayed in the python shell. Otherwise it depends on what you are using to display the data and also the kind of data stored in the file and it's encoding. Could you also please edit your question to include your complete code or the relevant parts for your question in the correct formating. This way it is easier for the rest of us to understand your code and to help you. Greetings

Comment: @ProgramNewbie As I told you in your previous question: Dat is *not* a format. We have no way of knowing the format of your particular file, and thus no way of knowing how to parse it, and in turn no way of helping you.

Comment: Thanks for your replies :) I just realised its a binary file haha.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "DAT" file format and, as you say, the file contains bytes - as do all files.

It's possible that the file contains binary data for which it's best to open the file in binary mode. You do that by specifying `b` as part of the `mode` parameter to `open()`, like this:

```
f = open('file.dat', 'rb')
data = f.read()    # read the entire file into data
print(data)
f.close()
```

Note that the full `mode` parameter is set to `rb` which means open the file in binary mode for reading.

A better way is to use `with`:

```
with open('file.dat', 'rb') as f:
    data = f.read()
    print(data)
```

No need to explicitly close the file.

If you know that the file contains *text*, possibly encoded in some specific encoding, e.g. UTF8, then you can specify the encoding when you open the file (Python 3):

```
with open('file.dat', encoding='UTF8') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line)
```

In Python 2 you can use `io.open()`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply :)